# confirm or alert boxes in safari(Windows) needs double click-why?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a very simple example in JavaScript like displaying an alert box on click event of an HTML button in SAFARI.The problem is, it requires double click to disapear from the screen.

Anyone have any idea about this?
 By the way I am using safari(5.0.5) on windows XP platform.

Here is the code:

```
<HTML> 
   <HEAD> 
     <TITLE>Using the ondblclick Event</TITLE> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function display() { 
          alert('this is BUTTON CLICK alert'); 
        } 

        function display2() { 
          alert('this is a ONLOAD alert'); 
        }
     </script> 
   </HEAD> 

   <BODY onLoad="display2();"> 
     <input type="button" id="b" value="Click Here!" onClick="display();" /> 
   </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

By the way I think this problem is not occuring on MAC OS as I had concerned with one of my friend.this problem is occuring on windows platform.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a Safari on Windows bug, not an issue with your code. Clicking the alert box in Safari / Windows will initially actually click through it onto your page.

This is a larger issue when the alert pops up over something causing the alert (ie: your button in this case), in which case clicking the "Ok" button generates another alert (since the click actually hit the button again).

I haven't tried it yet, but a suggestion to get around this is to use a jQuery dialogue instead. See [jquery: a safari bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005752/jquery-a-safari-bug) for reference.